# Retrieving file from remote server in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there any way I can invoke a command that gets the content of a file on the remote server and then writes the content to a file on my local machine?

Was hoping for something like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ###.##.###.## { $file= Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts } -Credential $cred
$file | Out-File \\path\to\local\machine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
$file = Invoke-Command -ComputerName ###.##.###.## { Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts } -Credential $cred
$file | Out-File \\path\to\local\machine
```

Comment: What if I use the `-AsJob` flag? How do I access the result of `Get-Content` instead of what `-AsJob` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use copy-item together with -FromSession argument. ??
I know that you need to open session first, but I believe it's more save for some special files.